Alembic doesn`t see classes. Doesn`t autogenerate code for migrations
I am new to alembic and sqlalchemy world
I want to make migrations using alembic.
Now I have
metadata = MetaData()

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Tests(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tests"
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    extraversion: Mapped[int]
    devotion: Mapped[int]
    self_control: Mapped[int]
    emotional_stability: Mapped[int]
    expressiveness: Mapped[int]

Then I use
 alembic revision --autogenerate

Got
def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands ###



And 3 more same-structured classes
Also mt db has no tables except of alembic_version table
My env.py
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context
from config import DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_USER
from models.models import metadata
from models.models import Users, Game, Logs, Tests
from init import *
# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

section = config.config_ini_section

config.set_section_option(section, "DB_HOST", DB_HOST)
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_NAME", DB_NAME)
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_PASS", DB_PASS)
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_PORT", DB_PORT)
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_USER", DB_USER)

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()


Alembic deleted this table due to I refactored it and dont see new version.
What`s the reason of that behaviour? How to fix that?
Will be greatful to any suggesion

replace target_metadata = metadata with target_metadata = Base.metadata import Base like you do with others
